# creating a simple_form which will be automatically send by mailer in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailer

i am getting this error:

undefined method `new' for Positionupdate:Module
Extracted source (around line #13):

```
 def create
    @positionupdate = Positionupdate.new(positionupdate_params)
    if @positionupdate.save
      PositionupdatesMailer.general_message(@positionupdate).deliver
    else
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I recommend reading [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I'm guessing that if you reduce your example significantly that you'll solve this issue on your own, and if not it'll make it a lot easier for others to help you solve it. And please, always include a stack trace when you get an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined method 'model\_name' for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130822/undefined-method-model-name-for-nilnilclass)

Comment: Looks like your `Positionupdate` is a module, not a class. In this case it can't be instantiated. Please, add code of `Positionupdate` to the question